# Does this Manifold exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

The excercise is the following:

Give an example or disprove:

There is at least one m-dimensional manifold that is compact in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that one chart is sufficient to get the whole manifold.

My idea was that this cannot be right. Reasoning: If yes, then there is a chart $\phi:U \rightarrow M$, where $U$ is open, but in that case $\phi^{-1}(M)$ is compact. This contradicts $U$ open since a chart is a bijection, so the inverse map should have got us $U$. My problem is, that this argument is very trivial and I am somewhat scared that it is wrong, so is there anyone who could check my argument?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument seems fine to me. There's just one ambiguity about one chart 'getting' the whole manifold. By your work it seems as if the chart map is surjective, but really if we know the manifold is compact couldn't a chart miss a few points but still give us enough information to determine the whole manifold. So in that sense we'd have a chart that gets the whole manifold without actually surjecting onto it.

An example of that would be charting a sphere by mapping an open set to everything but the north pole. From this chart you could determine that the manifold in question is definitely the sphere and hence you 'get it' from the single chart.